# Normalization in floating point representation

Tags: floating-point

What is the requirement of normalizing the mantissa in a floating point number?

Comment: In general, it's not required.  For particular formats (specifically IEEE-754), it *is* required, because that's fundamentally how that format works.

Answer (score 4):

In general, floating point normalization means choosing the exponent to prevent leading zeros in the significand.

There are two general reasons for preferring normalized numbers:

1. Consistency. For example, comparisons are simpler if each number that can be represented is always represented by the same bit pattern.
2. Precision. On rounding, making the leading significand digit non-zero allows retention of the maximum number of digits.

For base 2 floating point, there is an additional benefit. A binary digit that is known not to be zero must be one, so it does not have to be physically stored, saving a bit.

IEEE-754 does store very small magnitude numbers, those with the smallest exponent, with leading zeros, to get graceful underflow. However, even then the exponent is fixed so that each number has only one representation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), the mantissa needs to be normalized because:

- there needs to be an implicit leading 1 bit (that's just how the IEEE-754 format is defined)
- without normalization there would be a loss of precision, since you would not be using all of the mantissa bits